# Output specific entry from entries field based on position

Tags: craft3, entries-field

I have an entries field in a section, I am looking to output a certain selected entry from this field based on its position.

For example I want to out the 2nd or 3rd entry only from this entry field, what is the best way to do this without calling all the entries and looping through them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```twig
{% set allEntries = entry.entriesSelector.all() %}

<ul>
    <li>First: {{ allEntries[0].title }}</li>
    <li>Second: {{ allEntries[1].title }}</li>
    <li>Fourth: {{ allEntries[3].title }}</li>
    <li>Last: {{ allEntries|reverse[0].title }}</li>
</ul>
```